# Handling URI tasks manually

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to select an image from SD card in my android application.
I'm using URI to run device apps by below code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

I want to know if it is wise to handle `URI` tasks like above task by myself in my app or could it cause any trouble something like [**this**](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its fine and risk free. Incase you are trying to get images from Local storage, this is a good library :

https://github.com/jaydeepw/poly-picker

Comment: so why most of apps use URI? even google apps do it through URI

Comment: uniform resource identifier (URI) is basically just a Path to Access some media form Storage (local or online). Handling URIs is quite normal since apps. may access files and data on device or on server. Just handle the exceptions well and it wont cause any problem. Incase you are talking about hardcoded Server URIs in your app, well thats fine too, but for maintainability, you should well document all the URIs use in your App and also try to use them by assigning those to String/URI variables.